# Database export taking 12 hours and still running

Tags: oracle

I'm running an export for a company I haven't worked with before. 
Started export last night at 7:00pm and it's still running 12 hours later.
It's an agile 9.3.3 database, oracle 12c.
So far the dmp file is 18.7gb.
The oracle tables look like this
[image: oracle table]

Does it make sense for this export to take so long?
Thanks,
Laura

Comment: How fast is the disk subsystem (MB/s)?  Is the FRA on the same disk(s) as the data?  What does your RMAN script look like?

Comment: Check your alert log and review if the job is not hanged because lack of space. What is your db size?

Comment: You mean you are doing an export (`expdp`) ? Or is that an `rman` backup ? Those are very different tools with very different performance characteristics. Can you please show us the exact command you used?

Comment: It was an export:

Comment: It was an oracle db export:  exp agile/tartan file=agile9exp.dmp log=agile9exp.log owner=agile.  The job ran for nearly 24 hours. It did finally complete but the Dmp file was 33.1gb!  We checked cpu during export and it was fine. In fact I started application back up and users were on with Export running with no issues.  There is 900gb of disc available, 2 E5-2670 2.50Ghz CPU, 8 GB Ram.  Does that db dmp size make sense with the tablesizes above?